# Is there any security benifit to sent email message only as attachement?

Tags: email, email-spoofing

A well known company in Oil and Gas field, sends the email message as PDF attachment, with brief explanation, here is an example:

> ```
>  Dear  Mr Name,
>
>  Please review the attached document acknowledging your recent activity on
>  .....
>
>  Regards,
>
>  Company Recruiting Team
> ```

**Is there any security benefit behind this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In fact I'd be extremely hesitant to open one of these PDFs.

PDFs are notorious for spreading malware due to the various [sandbox escape vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Viruses_and_exploits) that have arisen over the years.

Emails don't necessarily verify the sender either - it's possible via DKIM but generally anyone could have sent that email to you (potentially loaded with malware) claiming it was sent from the company you trust.

It's a common trick to forge an email from a well known bank, attach a PDF which spreads malware then say in the message "see attached document to claim refund" or something similar.The message you posted reads suspiciously like that!

Comment: One could disable PDF Javascript easily, then PDFs become as safe as JPGs.

Comment: I agree with your argument, I think it might be used for recognizing company emails.